# Android: How to create a set of demo slides for the app which would be shown to the users when they open the app for the very first time?

Tags: java, android, xml, demo

I want to create a sort of tutorial for the first time users of my app. What is the correct way to go forward? Should I use .png s or some other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) is used to show those type of tutorials. You can look at this simple tutorial on [how to use viewpager for screen slides](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html). Then you can either have pngs on different fragments or also have different layouts depending upon your requirements.

Comment: But then how is it limited to just the uses who open the app for very first time and doesn't show up the next time they open the app?

Comment: Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store a boolean value that determines whether the tutorial has been shown or not. And each time the app is opened, check against that boolean.